# How would I call this method to clear database at the start of my App?

Tags: android, boolean, public

This Method is in my database class

```
 public boolean deletePlayers(long paramLong)
  {
    return this.mDb.delete("Players", "_id=" + paramLong, null) > 0;
  }
```

I want to call it in my Launch Activity class

```
public class LaunchActivity extends Activity {
 Button start;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);
        addListenerOnButton();
        PlayerDbAdapter db = new PlayerDbAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        db.open();
        db.deletePlayers(0);
        db.close();

    }
    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent); 
                                    finish();
```

This is what I tried

```
 PlayerDbAdapter db = new PlayerDbAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        db.open();


db.deletePlayers(0);
        db.close();
```

But I am still getting Data from previous entries in my listview. 
I also tried

```
db.deletePlayers(1);
```

To no avail

Full Adapter Class

```
public class PlayerDbAdapter {

private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Players";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+" (_id integer primary key autoincrement, Player_Name text not null, Player_Position text not null, Player_Number text not null, Team text not null);";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
  public static final String KEY_BODY = "Player_Name";
  public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
  public static final String KEY_TITLE = "Player_Position";
  public static final String KEY_NUMBER = "Player_Number";
  public static final String KEY_TEAM = "Team";
private static final String TAG = "PlayerDbAdapter";
  private final Context mCtx;
  private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
  private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;

  public PlayerDbAdapter(Context paramContext)
  {
    this.mCtx = paramContext;
  }

  public void close()
  {
    this.mDbHelper.close();
  }


  public long createPlayers(String playerName, String playerPosition, String playerNumber, String team)
  {
    ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();
    localContentValues.put(KEY_BODY, playerName);
    localContentValues.put(KEY_TITLE, playerPosition);
    localContentValues.put(KEY_NUMBER, playerNumber);
    localContentValues.put(KEY_TEAM, team);
    try{
        return this.mDb.insert("Players", null, localContentValues);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Juma", e.getMessage());
    }

    return 0;
  }

  public boolean deletePlayers(long paramLong)
  {
    return this.mDb.delete("Players", "_id=" + paramLong, null) > 0;
  }

  public Cursor fetchAllPlayers()
  {
    return this.mDb.query("Players", new String[] { "_id", "Player_Name", "Player_Position","Player_Number","Team" }, null, null, null, null, null);
  }

  public Cursor fetchPlayer(long paramLong)
    throws SQLException
  {
    Cursor localCursor = this.mDb.query(true, "Players", new String[] { "_id", "Player_Name", "Player_Position", "Player_Number","Team" }, "_id=" + paramLong, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (localCursor != null)
      localCursor.moveToFirst();
    return localCursor;
  }

  public PlayerDbAdapter open()
    throws SQLException
  {
    this.mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.mCtx);
    this.mDb = this.mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
  }

  public boolean updateNote(long paramLong, String paramString1, String paramString2,String paramString3,String paramString4)
  {
    ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();
    localContentValues.put("Player_Name", paramString1);
    localContentValues.put("Player_Position", paramString2);
    localContentValues.put("Player_Number", paramString3);
    localContentValues.put("Team", paramString4);
    return this.mDb.update("players", localContentValues, "_id=" + paramLong, null) > 0;
  }

  private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
  {
    DatabaseHelper(Context paramContext)
    {
      super(paramContext, "Players", null, 1);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase paramSQLiteDatabase)
    {
      paramSQLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Players (_id integer primary key autoincrement, Player_Name text not null, Player_Position text not null,  Player_Number text not null, Team text not null);");
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase paramSQLiteDatabase, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
    {
      Log.w("PlayerDbAdapter", "Upgrading database from version " + paramInt1 + " to " + paramInt2 + ", which will destroy all old data");
      paramSQLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Players");
      onCreate(paramSQLiteDatabase);
    }

  }
```

}

Comment: you want to delete all players?

Comment: Yes all player records in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `deletePlayers` with no param and call this if you want to clear all players.

```
public boolean deletePlayers()
{
    return this.mDb.delete("Players", "1", null) > 0;
}
```

Comment: If I get rid of the `(long paramLong)` it creates problem in one of my activity classes
`public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case DELETE_ID:
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                mDbHelper.deletePlayers(info.id);
                fillData();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }`
I get the error `deletePlayers` is not applicable for the argument (long)

Comment: So instead of change make another method as above.

Comment: Sorry didn't know about that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Post some code from your `DBAdapter` class, a quick shot can be replacing `getApplicationContext()` by `this` when you initialize the adapter. And also do you refresh your listview once you delete the item? If not please do so by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your listview adapter.

Comment: @Abdul tried notifyDataSetChanged (); ddint work. Updated OP with full  Adapter class

Comment: When you call `deletePlayers` what you get in return? True or False?

Comment: I breakpointed it and checked the variables this is what i found `mInnerTransactionIsSuccessful false`  is this what you meant?

Comment: No,your `deletePlayers` method returns a `boolean`;if it's successful it will return `true`;check like this: `if(deletePlayers(1)){Toast.makeText(this,"Must have deleted!",1000).show();} else{ //could not delete}`